# PHP to loop records from class method

Tags: php, foreach

I got below class to fetch records in database, how can use foreach to loop all data in page?

```
class User{

    public function get_user_listing($user_id, $mysqli){

        $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `listing` WHERE user_id='".$user_id."'");

       if($sql->num_rows > 0){
            return $query->result();
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

in my page, if I call:

```
$user = new User;
$listing = $user->get_user_listing($user_id, $mysqli);

foreach(listing as $value){
   echo $value->table_field;
}
```

But I think that is not a correct way.

Comment: no $ before user in: user->get_user_listing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the actual result `$sql`:

```
if($sql->num_rows > 0){
    return $sql;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Since you are returning a result set you need to fetch rows:

```
$user = new User;
$listing = $user->get_user_listing($user_id, $mysqli);

while($row = $listing->fetch_object()){
   echo $row->table_field;
}
```

Or you could add the fetch loop to the class function and return an array of `$row[]` objects.

Also, I would make some changes here:

```
private $mysqli;

public function __construct($mysqli) {
    $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
}
public function get_user_listing($user_id) {
    $mysqli = $this->mysqli;
    //or just use $sql = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `listing` WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id'");
    //etc...
}
```

Then:

```
$user = new User($mysqli);
$listing = $user->get_user_listing($user_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use a prepared statement to protect from SQL injection. And check the returned value from `get_user_listing` for false or undef.

```
public function get_user_listing($user_id, $mysqli){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `listing` WHERE user_id=?";
    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)) {

        $stmt->bind_param("i", $user_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        return $result;
    }
}


$user = new User;
$result = $user->get_user_listing($user_id, $mysqli);

if(isset($result))
{
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        print $row['table_field'];
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}
```